# Symmetric sum of powers

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

Let $\mathbb C [x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be a ring of polynomials with complex coefficients. We then define the symmetric polynomials 
\begin{align*}
S_0 &= 1 \\
S_1 &= x_1 + \cdots + x_n \\
S_2 &= x_1x_2 + x_1 x_3 + \cdots + x_{n-2}x_n+ x_{n-1}x_n \\
\cdots \\
S_n &= x_1x_2\cdots x_n
\end{align*}
and the symmetric $k$-power polynomials, for every $k\in \mathbb N$,
\begin{align*}
P_{k, 0} &= 1 \\
P_{k, 1} &= x_1^k + \cdots + x_n^k \\
P_{k, 2} &= x_1^kx_2^k + x_1^k x_3^k + \cdots + x_{n-2}^k x_n^k + x_{n-1}^k x_n^k \\
\cdots \\
P_{k, n} &= x_1^k x_2^k \cdots x_n^k
\end{align*}

Newton's identities give us 
\begin{equation}
P_{k,1} = \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1} S_i P_{k-i,1}
\end{equation}
which implies that $P_{k,1}$ can be written as a polynomial of $S_1, \dots, S_n$ with integral coefficients. My question is

> Is it possible to write $P_{k,i}$ as a polynomial of $S_1, \dots, S_n$ with integral coefficients?

Comment: Of course it is possible. They are invariant in regard to the permutation of their variables, and hence may be expressed via the elementary symmetric polynomials $S_k$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, thank you! I didn't think there was such a general result... Anyway, now I've been able to find some stuff online that explains that ;).